# Networkx not working in vs code but working ipython

Tags: python, python-3.x

it is installed and I'm able to use it with ipython but its throwing error in vs code
    `import networkx as nx ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'`

```
import networkx` could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource
```

please resolve the issues

Comment: did you `pip install` the module?

Comment: Did you configure vscode to use the same Python environment you use with ipython?

Answer (score 0):

In you terminal or command prompt, run the following.

`pip install networkx`
`pip install matplotlib`

Mine is resolved like this. I hope your can be as well